# Informatica Job encounters "Actual File does not have execute permission" error

Tags: informatica, informatica-cloud

I'm trying to create a simple mapping task job in Informatica Cloud that copies a text file from a subdirectory to its' parent directory. Even if I give both folders 777 permissions on the secure agent where the process is run, I get the following error when I run the process:
"[ERROR]
com.informatica.cloud.api.adapter.runtime.exception.FatalRuntimeException:
Actual File does not have execute permission!!"

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Where does the file exist? Is it on the server where this wkflow is running, or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

We found the issue. Salesforce automatically started enforcing "enhanced domains" in sandboxes even though our org isn't ready to use that feature yet. I learned from my client that this was only happening in our sandbox, and the issue started happening when this change was implemented. We temporarily disabled the feature in the Salesforce sandbox and will reactivate it once our third party vendor has our org ready to use enhanced domains.